# grep regular expression not matching zero correctly

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm having some issues with grep regular expressions. I'm trying to grep some ascii coded hexidecimal data where the characters are all lower case

My grep statement is as follows:

```
grep -E "01[a-f0-9]{2}81[a-f0-9]0" log.log
```

Most of the matches in the file look ok, except there are numerous matches that are as follows

```
010481ec070000
01b481ec070000
01508129070521
```

I can't work out why these strings are matching. They should not match because 81 must be followed by a hex character then a zero.

I have done some further investigation. If I place these three strings in a separate file, and grep that file. I get no matches. Not quite sure what is going on here.

This is grep 2.12.

here is part of the raw data in the file. These are all lines that have matched. And still match after exporting LC_ALL=C

```
input data : 011a81a907000b3002004070eaa3d2240fa81272011763dd0040002001
input data : 010481e1070000
input data : 010481ea070000
input data : 011a81a207000b980f0040681f2b11d2f60202dc003669ba0140006100
input data : 014681ab07002140010040d2e457f8c00494ed5e014362bf0240006101ae0500404ee311f402feb2165401c562450240005801db08044068f09ff6a6005af953008062470640004d01
input data : 010481e3070000
input data : 013081ac070016c0000040f6d963fcb4f7e8127c0103637b0140006f01bf0200408ae344fdd2043eed72018362a30240006f01
input data : 010481e4070000
input data : 011a81ad07000b5c06006064f96804901154fed2008e66ff0f4000a401
input data : 010481e5070000
input data : 014681ae070021170d004069f196134cf6a805b4000769b6034000be014e0e004092e80820da0b82fbfa000c6c5c014000bf01880a004020d9ce21f4efd40954011469a1004000ae01
input data : 011a81a607000bef0d0060d60dd6edf8f18e104e015b63d3014000da00
input data : 011a81af07000b4c0800401cfbb0184a0c28f7fa00516931024000e101
input data : 015c81a007002c12050020f2ff640028007afd00801205f70540000400280c00404f016a0a10fbd0012a00e769ff0f400018005d020040e3fabd21e00830f4d200c769d80140000300030a004042030
```

Comment: seems like an older grep version !

Comment: here, no matching found by your grep command with your input (the 3 lines) . grep ver `gnu grep 2.14`

Comment: Something is fishy. I cannot reproduce your results either, and the regex is simple enough that a bug is highly unlikely.  Are you SURE you are showing us the regex that is executing, AND the entire input lines?  Could it be matching some other part of the line you haven't shown?  You don't anchor to start or end of line...

Comment: I have done some further investigation. If I place these three strings in a separate file, and grep that file. I get no matches. Not quite sure what is going on here.

Comment: SHOW THE ENTIRE INPUT LINES, not just the strings you expect to match.

Comment: None of the three strings you give as matches appear in the input data sample.

Comment: Here's a guess: The _actual_ regex you are using is `01[a-f0-9]{2}81[a-f0-9]{2}0` -- this would explain ALL your matches.

Comment: the command I am running is exactly grep -E "01[a-f0-9]{2}81[a-f0-9]0" -a log.log

Comment: The file I am grepping is hundreds of MB in size. There are many many lines that match the regexp correctly and many that appear to be matching incorrectly as I have shown some examples of.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it with the environment variable `LC_ALL=C`. The locale affects the way `grep` interprets character ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the command is exactly as you say...  The quotes are right, there's no filename glob going on before grep gets the arguments, you don't have {0} instead of 0, etc....

I wonder if the -a (treat binary file as text) is the culprit.  Binary output could be processed by the terminal.  (That's how we change colors or do curses positioning or whatnot.)

What if you had binary in there that erased part of the line?  Say control-H's...

What happens if you pipe the grep output through ***od -c*** (or perhaps ***od -a*** or ***od -t a*** if you have it).

What happens if you store the output in a file, pull out just one such line with grep, and look at it with od?